# I2C user-space read/write issues

Tags: c, linux, i2c

I'm writing a user-space program to read and write to/from an EEPROM using open(), ioctl(), read(), and write(), but it doesn't seem to be working the way I expect.

I guess first of all I have to ask, is the entire [I2C protocol for read and write](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/i2c/i2c-protocol) handled by calls to read() and write() with an I2C file descriptor? [According to the link here](https://xgoat.com/wp/2007/11/11/using-i2c-from-userspace-in-linux/), the entire transaction is handled by read() and write().

If that is so, then how do read() and write() know which register address to read from? Most places I've read say to use the first byte of the data buffer passed to read() and write() to store the address of the register to read from or write to. But then what if the device I am communicating with uses 16-bit register addresses and register data? How do read() and write() know if the address is 8 or 16 bits long?

Comment: Register addresses aren't part of the I2C protocol, they're part of the message. Each device can define its own protocol and format for messages, and you do what's appropriate for the device you're using. `read` and `write` don't *need* to know how long the register address is, or *what* one is, they're just moving bits.

Comment: The spec/data sheet for your device should hold the info for programming it.

Comment: You must have missed this line of code in the [second link you posted](https://xgoat.com/wp/2007/11/11/using-i2c-from-userspace-in-linux/):  `ioctl( fd, I2C_SLAVE, ADDRESS )`

Comment: @david-grayson, is that not the device address, not the register address on the device?

Comment: BTW, sorry if these questions are dumb, but I've never worked at this low level before.

Comment: Last question if anyone want to answer: when doing an `ioctl(file_descriptor, I2C_SLAVE, device_address)`, should the device address be bit-shifted to the left 1 bit since the address is only 7 bits and to account for the read/write bit?

Answer (score 3):

I think the underlying protocol is implemented with three system calls: `read`, `write`, and `ioctl`, as described [in the kernel I²C documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface).  However, I recommend using `libi2c` so you don't have to worry about those details.  I have written about how to use that library here:

http://blog.davidegrayson.com/2012/06/using-ic-on-raspberry-pi.html

I successfully wrapped it in a C++ class, which you can see here:

https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/minimu9-ahrs/blob/master/I2CBus.cpp

Also, in I²C, device addresses are 7-bit.  If your device implements some kind of 16-bit address, that would probably be implemented inside data transfers to the 7-bit address of a device.